# Unreasonable difference between MySQL dump and load times

Tags: load, mysql

I'm dumping a database into a file (piping the dump through gzip) and it takes about 2 minutes to create a 300MB dump.sql.gz file.

When loading the file back into MySQL (the dump begins with dropping the tables), the load takes around 30 minutes!!

What can be the reason for such a huge difference in times? Are there any general tips for drastically reducing the load times?

Thanks.

Comment: is it updating indexes? Can you turn off indexing then rebuild after the load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is that writing to a database is MUCH more expansive than reading from it.  The database has to make sure writes are transactional, it has to update indexes, expand files, and so on.

Another resaon is that MySQL dumps a SQL version of your data, like a ton of `insert` statements in a big text file.  That's very slow.  Backups from other databases are usually binary files that can be written over the original database, which is faster than restoring one row at a time.

Comment: Binary file images always restore faster - there's nothing to stop you from doing this on MySQL

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to do it from InnoDB to MyISAM?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andomar's answer - you'll get a significant improvement adding '--delayed-insert' and '--extended-insert' to the dump.

Comment: Are you sure, it took me 43 minutes instead of an half an hour to load the dump created the way you suggested..

Comment: Should be MUCH faster - I'm surprised - eliminated other causes?